# How to restore my_backup.tar in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I had used Backup gem to create backup of Postgresql DB.

" backup perform -t my_backup " generate a my_backup.tar file in 2012.10.06.12.30.11 folder

tar file contain image.tar and .sql file.

What is the method to restore database from this tar file?

Answer (score 3):

Make a rake task (assuming your SQL file is named `foo.sql`)

```
namespace :db do
  task import: :environment do
    import_path = "/tmp/import"
    sql_file = "foo.sql"
    database_config = Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]

    # Unpack
    system "tar xf my_backup.tar -C #{import_path}"
    system "gzip -df #{import_path}/#{sql_file}.gz"

    # Import
    system "psql --username=#{database_config['username']} -no-password #{database_config['database']} < #{import_path}/#{sql_file}"
  end
end
```

Make sure your database user has a `superuser` or `createdb` role.